# queue.size in Sidekiq is not updated in real time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq with ActiveJob. I want to balance the queues. So I use this way.

```
while queue.size < 10
  SomeJob.perform_later(some_args) # This should add one job to the queue right away, but it doesn't, it takes some time for the job to enter the queue.
end
```

This is failing in a bad way. This will schedule 50, 60 or more jobs. The cause is that the queue is not populated by jobs directly, but instead, it takes some time for the jobs to enter the queue. So the method `queue.size` will return `0` for a few seconds then gets the real queue size.

**UPDATE:** 
I found the issue. It turns out that the class I use to schedule the jobs is a configured one, the configuration at some point was SomeJob.set(wait: wait_time), and wait_time was 0. active job will put the job into scheduled set for some time (less than a second or so) before it enters the queue. This is why the queue.size didn't reflect what I expected to be in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `queue` is already initialized, and you're not reinitializing the new `queue` object every time a job is enqueued. It won't "update in real time" as you say (similarly to how you'd have to call #reload on an ActiveRecord object)

More efficient than reinitializing, same effect:

```
size = queue.size
max_queue_size = 10
number_of_jobs_to_perform = max_queue_size - size

number_of_jobs_to_perform = 0 if number_of_jobs_to_perform < 0 

number_of_jobs_to_perform.times do
  SomeJob.perform_later(args)
end
```

Edit: if you really must, use a proc, such as `Proc.new { queue.size }.times do ...`

Comment: Sidekiq is using Redis list as queues. The thing is, even when I create a Redis client and use it to check for the queue size or for the queue content, it doesn't return the right size right away. This is not how Redis lists work. Since Redis is single threaded, Pushing an element to the list then check the size, it's garenteed that the list is already updated and the size is correct.

Comment: This means tht Sidekiq is delaying the queue population somehow.

Comment: I don't think it's delaying it as much as it's probably just sub-ms latency. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L218

But regardless, your `queue.size` gets read once by the ruby interpreter, and then your loop runs `queue.size` times because `queue.size` is an integer. A proc should help.

Comment: It turns out that the class I use to queue the job is configured with a wait: 0. Some where in my code I used `job_class = SomeJob.set(wait: wait_time)`, so when the job is scheduled with `job_class.perform_later(args)` it wait for some time before it enters the queue. So, this is not a Sidekiq issue, but my code's.

Comment: Sidekiq::Queue#size does not cache the result but hits Redis every time.